Random time change and ergodicity
I guess it is a standard question in ergodic theory but I failed to find any reference to similar problems and I have no clue on how to tackle it.
Let $(B_{t})_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ be a standard Brownian motion and $(\tau_{n+1}-\tau_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ a stationary and ergodic sequence. We assume $\tau$ and $B$ to be independent.
The sequence $\tau_{n}$ is a sequence of random events and we are looking at the oscillations of the Brownian motion between two consecutive events. This amounts to study the random sequence $\Delta_{n} = B_{\tau_{n+1}}-B_{\tau_{n}}$ which I believe is iid by the strong Markov property.
Question 1. Is there anything known about $(\Delta_{n},\tau_{n+1}-\tau_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$? More specifically, is it ergodic?
If question 1 has a positive answer, what happens if we replace the condition $B$ Brownian with a weaker one, such as $B$ ergodic with stationary but not necessarily independent increments.
Question 2. Under this weaker requirement, is $(\Delta_{n}, \tau_{n+1}-\tau_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ ergodic?
I am not looking for definitive answers, but mostly for references where similar problems might have been approached.
